# Dependency errors in Ubuntu installation

Tags: apt, openssl, certificates

I'm trying to fix an APT setup in an Ubuntu server to which I only have SSH access and can't make head or tail of the dependency errors.

I've run `sudo apt-get install -f`, and get the following:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up ssl-cert (1.0.23ubuntu2) ...
dpkg: error processing ssl-cert (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of postgresql-common:
 postgresql-common depends on ssl-cert (>= 1.0.11); however:
  Package ssl-cert is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing postgresql-common (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of postgresql-8.4:
 postgresql-8.4 depends on postgresql-common (>= 104~); however:
  Package postgresql-common is not configured yet.
 postgresql-8.4 depends on ssl-cert; however:
  Package ssl-cert is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing postgresql-8.4 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of postgresql:
 postgresql depends on postgresql-8.4; however:
  Package postgresql-8.4 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing postgresql (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 ssl-cert
 postgresql-common
 postgresql-8.4
 postgresql
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

What exactly does this mean? Is there a circular dependency?

I've tried installing the required dependency `ssl-cert` but it doesn't work either.

I can't use `dpkg` directly either.

Any tips on how to resolve this, or could someone help me to better understand the problem? Is there any additional information that I should provide?

===

**EDIT:**
Running `sudo sh -x /path/to/config.postinst configure` yields the following output:

```
+ . /usr/share/debconf/confmodule
+ [ !  ]
+ PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1
+ export PERL_DL_NONLAZY
+ [  ]
+ exec /usr/share/debconf/frontend /var/lib/dpkg/info/ssl-cert.postinst configure
```

Does that mean that the script fails to execute the last line?

Running `sudo /usr/share/debconf/frontend /var/lib/dpkg/info/ssl-cert.postinst configure` completes silently but a subsequent `echo $?` yields `1`, indicating that an error did occur.

When I add `set -x` to the top of the file, and then run the `sudo ... frontend ... configure` command, it fails at:

```
make-ssl-cert generate-default-snakeoil
```

`set -x`ing this file as well fails at:

```
 openssl req -config /tmp/tmp.wPl6nkzKYm -new -x509 -days 3650 -nodes -out /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem -keyout /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
```

Running this command with `sudo` gives:

```
Generating a 1024 bit RSA private key
.....................++++++
.......................++++++
writing new private key to '/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key'
-----
problems making Certificate Request
53829:error:0D07A097:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_mbstring_ncopy:string too long:a_mbstr.c:154:maxsize=64
```

I'm not familiar with OpenSSL; what's going on here?

(Also, should I fork this to a new question? Has this question's scope been exceeded?)

Comment: you have to edit the file and add `set -x` at the start of `ssl-cert.postinst`.

Comment: Is your machines' FQDN very long?

Comment: What's the output of `hostname`?

Comment: @Braiam: `hostname` outputs the correct hostname, which is an 11-character string according to both `hostname | wc -c` and my eyes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I went around for a bit, and seems that [your "Company name"](http://openssl.6102.n7.nabble.com/Max-length-of-company-field-td16133.html) is too long for openSSL. [This is a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ssl-cert/+bug/1004682). You should upgrade your system to precise or later to fix this.

Remove any blocking package and upgrade your system. That should fix the issue.

Comment: This series of commands gives me the same error; there appears to be an error in the configuration.

Comment: @WChargin updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for this; how can I find what my "company name" is?

Comment: Ah; found it! Thanks! This appears to solve (the first step of) the problem. (For anyone reading this later it's the argument to `openssl` after `-config`)

Comment: @WChargin precise don't have the `1.0.23ubuntu2` version of openssl, but `1.0.28`. According to the [package list](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/ssl-cert) you are using lucid. I strongly recommend to do a full upgrade of your system.

Answer (score 2):

The key excerpt from the output is this error while running the post-installation script for the `ssl-cert` package:

> ```
> Setting up ssl-cert (1.0.23ubuntu2) ...
> dpkg: error processing ssl-cert (--configure):
> subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
> ```

All of the subsequent errors are a consequence of the failure to complete the installation of `ssl-cert`.

To find out exactly [how the postinst script failed](http://elfstone.nl/2010/06/02/debian-packages-debugging-postinst/), run

```
sudo sh -x /var/lib/dpkg/info/ssl-cert.postinst configure
```

Once you manage to debug the root cause, run `sudo apt-get install -f` again.

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: As suggested in the link, edit `ssl-cert.postinst`, inserting `set -x`, and try running the postinst script again.